# How can I find out how much time was left to sleep after thread was interrupted?

Tags: java

I have a thread, on which i am calling sleep() for a specific amount of time. If the thread is interrupted, I need a way to know how much time was left. Is there a built-in way to do this?

P.S. I have a strong suspicion that this may be an XY problem. (i.e. I'm thinking about this completely wrong)

Comment: Regarding that XY problem: what is it you're actually trying to do? If the reason you want to sleep for N millis (and not fewer) is that you want to schedule a task to happen regularly, [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [Executors.newScheduledThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool-int-) may be appropriate.

Comment: if you really need to know  how much time it has slept, then just measure it using `System.nanoTime();` Although if it was interrupted, then it means that it was asked to terminate, so it's irrelevant how much time it wasted sleeping. Instead you should focus on providing a graceful termination on interruption.

Comment: The interrupt is meant to be more like a pause in the sleep, rather than a terminate

Answer (score 1):

When starting the sleep, determine the end of sleep first. If the sleep is interrupted and should be resumed, sleep for `originalEndTime - now` ms.

It's so not clear what exactly you're trying to do though tasks, you're probably right about the XY.